# I want to read the Registry value and want to store that value to environment variable using powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, registry

I'm new to the powershell , i want to search the registry where that value is stored and want that value to be stored in the environment variable , Eg: Java

$Registry_Key = "HKLM:\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8.0_73"
Get-ItemProperty -path $Registry_Key -name JavaHome

I can find the registry value for it , but i was not able to store the value into the environment variable

Comment: Why have you tag C#?

Comment: you can use .Net Environment class to do that but what variable do you want update? Environment variable set at machine and user lever is nothing but a registry entry....So If you are planning to read "JavaHome" from registry and update the env variable "JavaHome" then you are just reading and updating same registry entry

Comment: Please read the question i want to get the value from registry and store it to environment variable using powershell , I used C# coz i want to use that value to pull from environment variable not registry

Comment: I think you did not understand what I explained....In Powershell, you can use .Net module, Powershell supports it. So when you say *i want to get the value from registry and store it to environment variable using powershell* that storing it to env var can be done using **Environment** class in **Powershell** but as explained it is important to first understand what Variable you want to update in env var..

Comment: I know .net Module man , i'm asking how you can do it . I'm getting the value from registry if you check the script which is written above ,but i'm not able to put it in the environment variable now  using powershell . eg variable  JAVA_HOME i want to use in environment variable

Comment: I understood your question when I read it first time...I just wanted to know what are you trying to do....What Environment variable are you trying to update reason explained in previous comment.When someone asks question only reason for that is to give appropriate answer. Anyways, I have posted an answer and it should help you

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$Registry_Key = "HKLM:\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8.0_73" 
$registryValue  = Get-ItemProperty -path $Registry_Key -name JavaHome
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Java_Home", "$registryValue", "User")
```

Comment: I have used this above script and it don't work clearly please check it .

Comment: How did you use it? when you say it did not work clearly? what happened?

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine...Post your complete powershell script

Comment: Cannot find an overload for "SetEnvironmentVariable" and the argument count: "3".
At line:3 char:1
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Java_Home", $registryValue, "User")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: $Registry_Key = "HKLM:\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8.0_73" 
$registryValue  = Get-ItemProperty -path $Registry_Key -name JavaHome   This works fine try it :) 
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Java_Home", $Env:Path +";$registryValue", "User")

Comment: Yeah..I was about to tell you to wrap registryvalue variable in double quotes ("")... registryValue might have some character which might be causing problem when trying to call method....